# Is it possible to assign default values to attributes when using rails scaffold command? How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

For example, I want to generate a scaffold with a boolean field that defaults to `false`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can not do that from command line.

You can read about available modifiers to pass from command line [in docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#passing-modifiers).

Also, very nice practical (a bit old but still useful) [article](http://railsguides.net/advanced-rails-model-generators/).

You can do at least the following stuff:

```
# Specify the type of the field
rails g model user email age:integer
# Add index for column
rails g model user email:index location_id:integer:index
# Add uniq index for column
rails g model user pseudo:string:uniq
# Set limit for field of integer, string, text and binary fields:
rails generate model user pseudo:string{30}
# generate decimal field with scale and precision:
rails generate model product 'price:decimal{10,2}'
# You can combine any single curly brace option with the index options:
rails generate model user username:string{30}:uniq
# options to generate reference columns (fields which are used in rails as foreign keys):
rails generate model photo album:references
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes one way you can try to give the length but not able to give default value

```
rails g scaffold users firstname:string{50}
```

Comment: I am not sure, if you can set default from command like. I will test it out.

Comment: Is there a way to verify this? I mean after running the command, is it possible to verify if it has set the default?

Comment: @Awa, yes, just open the generated migration and check if it has `default: false`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it doesn't have it. Am sure its not possible then

Comment: @Awa that is why I say it is not possible in my answer :) Have a read through links I provided

Comment: @AndreyDeineko is right it is not possible but you can give length by my way